# SQL1092N The requested command or operation failed because the user ID does not have the authority to perform the requested command or operation

Tags: db2, connection

I have found this error while executing db2 create database testdb.
I experimented a lot and found solution for my problem. Hope this solution will help for others as well.
First I added my windows userID to DBADMNS and DBUSRS group(Under computer management>local users and groups>groups).
Secondly, I executed "db2set DB2_GRP_LOOKUP=local" command in cmd.
Thridly, I didn't run cmd by right click and run as administrator but I opened cmd and ran following command
"runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd"
then I ran the command "db2 create database testdb" again and it worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question.